# Extract nodes and edges as road network from osm.pbf file with python

Tags: openstreetmap, network, road, network-dataset

I have downloaded the israël's osm.pbf file from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html). I want to extract the road network's country, which means a list of edges between two nodes ids. For a such tiny country, this list should be quite small. However when I run the python code below, it took hours and hours to perform this little task.

```
from pyrosm.pyrosm import OSM
filename = "israel-and-palestine-latest.osm.pbf"
obj = OSM(filepath=filename)
nodes,edges = obj.get_network(network_type="driving",nodes=True)
```

Do you know any alternative to speed up the task? I do not need the geometry of each node, maybe it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Downloading):

```
osmosis  --read-pbf israel-and-palestine-latest.osm.pbf  \
 --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node  \
 --write-pbf israel-and-palestine-latest-highways.osm.pbf
```

The documentation is e.g. [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.41)